# how to show procedure output in php

Tags: php

i am a php beginer. i want to call a mysql procedure and display the output rows returned by the procedure. the code is below

**mysql**

```
delimiter //



     create procedure get_ques_list(in p_ques_ctgr varchar(10))

    begin

    select ques from question_list where ques_categorey=p_ques_ctgr
    order by ques;

end //
```

delimiter ;

**php code**

```
$result=mysql_query("CALL GET_QUES_LIST('S_001')"); 


while($row=mysql_result($result,0,0))

{

    echo $row['ques'];  
}
```

but it is giving warning messgge

**Warning: mysql_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in**

**but the same code works fine and display 5 rows if i use query instead of calling procedure**

```
$result=mysql_query("select ques from question_list where 
ques_categorey='S_001' order by ques");
```

procedure is also working fine when executed in `mysql`

can anyone tell where m going wrong in that??

**any help is appreciated**

Comment: i have also used mysql_fetch_array()

Comment: You should use PDO class instead of the old mysql_query, may also prove easier to manage. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php